# k8s - give permission for all resources

Tags: kubernetes

Im trying to create a job to list all resources because my connection is terrible. Is there any way to give permission to a pod run the below command?

Here is ClusterRole that I am trying:

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: istio-system
  name: workaround
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:  
  - '*'
- apiGroups: ['*']
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:  
  - '*'
```

The command is:

```
kubectl api-resources --verbs=list --namespaced -o name | xargs -n 1 kubectl get -n ibm-rancher
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to give your workload an admin role, you can use the prebuilt `cluster-admin` cluster role which should be available on every k8s cluster.
See the docs for more details - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/#user-facing-roles